# How do you specify region for AWS SDK for Python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

From cli I can execute the command:
`aws s3api list-objects –-bucket BUCKETNAME -—region REGIONAME`

How do I equivalently specify the region for `botocore3` `list_objects_v2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Python Docs there are a lot of examples of how to do this. WHen you set a Service Client using the AWS SDK, all languages let you set a region. The AWS SDK for Python is no different.

Here is a code example that shows you how to set the region when creating a Service Client.

```
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config

proxy_definitions = {
    'http': 'http://proxy.amazon.com:6502',
    'https': 'https://proxy.amazon.org:2010'
}

my_config = Config(
    region_name='us-east-2',
    signature_version='v4',
    proxies=proxy_definitions,
    proxies_config={
        'proxy_client_cert': '/path/of/certificate'
    }
)

client = boto3.client('kinesis', config=my_config)
```

More information can be found here:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#guide-configuration

Comment: Thanks (for both replies). A very basic question, still bot amateur. I;d noticed the region in the client but wasn't sure if it was for the buket or not.

Answer (score 10):

It can be added while setting params

```
s3_client = boto3.client(
             's3',
             aws_access_key_id='access_key_here',
             aws_secret_access_key='access_key_secret_here',
             config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4'),
             region_name='region_here'
            )
```

Then your request to get object lists:

```
response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix='', Delimiter='/')
```